Finite Differences:
I am having difficulty implementing finite differences in the correct columns of my code.
f[x_] := -2*x^4 + 8*x^3 + 11*x^2 - 3*x 
n = 7; x = Range[1, n];
y = f /@ x;
diffs = NestList[Differences, y, Length[y] - 1] // Transpose;
tabela = Prepend[Transpose[{x, y, Sequence @@ diffs}], {"x", "y", "1ª Diferença", "2ª Diferença", "3ª Diferença", "4ª Diferença"}];
xmin = 0; xmax = 10; 
ymin = -1600; ymax = 200; 
p = Plot[f[x], {x, xmin, xmax}, PlotRange -> {ymin, ymax}, PlotStyle -> Red];
pDiscreto = ListPlot[Transpose[{x, y}], PlotRange -> {ymin, ymax},PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.02], Blue}];


Show[p, pDiscreto]
Grid[tabela, Frame -> All]


The first difference is {56, 74, 20, -154, -496, -1054}, the second is {18, -54, -174, -342, -558}, the third is {-72, -120, -168, -216}, and the fourth is {-48, -48, -48}.

NestList[Differences, y, Length[y] - 1] produces a list of lists of decreasing length rather than, say, a matrix. So it cannot be transposed.

Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_] := -2*x^4 + 8*x^3 + 11*x^2 - 3*x
n = 7; x = Range[1, n];
y = f /@ x;

diffs = NestList[Differences, y, Length[y] - 1] // Rest // 
    Flatten[#, {{2}, {1}}] & // PadRight[#, {7, 8}, "-"] & // 
  Transpose

tabela = Prepend[
  Transpose[{x, y, Sequence @@ diffs}], {"x", "y", "1ª Diferença", 
   "2ª Diferença", "3ª Diferença", "4ª Diferença"}]

xmin = 0; xmax = 10;
ymin = -1600; ymax = 200;

p = Plot[f[x], {x, xmin, xmax}, PlotRange -> {ymin, ymax}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red];

pDiscreto = 
  ListPlot[Transpose[{x, y}], PlotRange -> {ymin, ymax}, 
   PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.02], Blue}];

Show[p, pDiscreto]
Grid[tabela, Frame -> All]




Thank you for the correction, indeed I was unaware of the line of code where you made the correction."


We can use Difference[#,n] to get n order difference.
Flatten[#,{{2},{1}}] can be use to transpose the irregular matrice.

Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_] := -2*x^4 + 8*x^3 + 11*x^2 - 3*x
n = 7; x = Range[1, n];
y = f /@ x;
list = Flatten[
   Join[{x, y}, Table[Differences[y, i], {i, 1, 6}]], {{2}, {1}}];
tabela = 
  Prepend[list, {"x", "y", "1ª Diferença", "2ª Diferença", 
    "3ª Diferença", "4ª Diferença"}];
Grid[tabela, Frame -> All]



The sole purpose of this post is to illustrate DifferenceDelta  (and DiscretePlot):  in-built function(s) for discrete calculus in Wolfram Language/Mathematica. I have voted for @Syed's answer which is instructive and follows the style and format of OP code.
(* formulae for i-th finite differenc *)

der = DifferenceDelta[f[i], {i, #}] & /@ Range[0, 4]

(* evaluating finite differences at relevant values*)

val = Reverse@Table[Range[1, j], {j, 3, 7}];
eval = Transpose@
   PadRight[MapThread[Function[u, #1 /. i -> u] /@ #2 &, {der, val}], Automatic, "_"];

(* Displaying result*)

tab = TableForm[eval, 
   TableHeadings -> {Range[7], {"f[x]", "First difference", 
      "Second difference", "Third difference", "Fourth Difference"}}, 
   TableAlignments -> Right];
Column[{Show[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 7}, PlotRange -> Full], 
   DiscretePlot[f[j], {j, 0, 7}, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}],
    ImageSize -> Medium], tab}, Frame -> All]

The formulae:
{-3 i + 11 i^2 + 8 i^3 - 
  2 i^4, -2 (-7 - 19 i - 6 i^2 + 4 i^3), -6 (-7 + 4 i^2), -24 (1 + 
    2 i), -48}

Result:

I reiterate this just to illustrate in-built WL/Mma functions. Stylistic/format choices are for user.
